# What are API "burst" requests and how to make them in python?

Tags: rest, api, request, python-requests

When reading the API document for places such as [Coinbase docs](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#rate-limits), I see that they impose two limits on API requests: one regular and one in bursts.

> We throttle public endpoints by IP: 3 requests per second, up to 6
>   requests per second in bursts.

What does it make to make requests in "bursts" and how is that done in python?
I tied Googling this and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It simply mean that you are allowed on average 3 requests per second, or for a short time (i.e. burst) 6 requests seconds.

Most likely when you make too often 6 or more calls per second you will get rate limited.

Comment: But it's unclear; is "short time" less than a second? Also it does not make sense: do I get "Too many requests" if I request over 3 per second? I try to understand the precise definition of it, in order to be able to get as many requests as quickly as possible.

Comment: @Newskooler did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: Not really. Do you understand it @MosesGitau?

Comment: It sounds plausible that they'd have 2 methods in place: 1 way that ensures that, e.g. every minute, the average has to be be below 3 seconds. And at the same time there could be one that checks for every second that it is not more than 6 times per second. So you're best off with just trying to hit exactly 3 times per second all the time, and in case there are hiccups in the system you won't be immediately banned.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway limits the steady-state requests per second (RPS) across all APIs within an AWS account, per Region. It also limits the burst (that is, the maximum bucket size) across all APIs within an AWS account, per Region. In API Gateway, **the burst limit represents the target maximum number of concurrent request submissions that API Gateway will fulfill** before returning 429 Too Many Requests error responses.